# Adding custom post deployers in Activiti 5.17

Tags: drools, activiti

I would like to add a new specific **customPostDeployers** in **Activi 5.17**. 
Not the default org.activiti.engine.impl.rules.RulesDeployer but my own class to import DecisitionTableRules from an XLS file.

On my Unit test, I use a **activiti.cf.xml** file to declare my CustomPostDeployer in a processEngineConfiguration bean but how to set it in the activiti config and where ?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I done my configuration into **activiti-custom-context.xml** as described into the 16.1.2. Configuring the Process Engine chapter of the Activiti documentation.

Comment: We have successfully used the activiti-custom-context.xml in 5.17 to add custom parsers.